# Prove the solution of $f''(x)-4f(x)=0$ is $f(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^{p+1}}{(2p)!}x^{2p}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm wondering about this question :

We have the differential equation $f''(x)-4f(x)=0$ and we want to find $f$ as a power serie with $f(0)=4$ and $f'(0)=0$. I would like to prove the only solution is $f(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^{p+1}}{(2p)!}x^{2p}$ as well as express it using usual functions.

With the usual method to solve differential equations with power series I arrive to a recursive relation $(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-4a_n=0$. How should we proceed to come to the final result ?

Thank you

Comment: Use your above equation to solve for $a_{n+2}$. Write a few of the coefficients out, starting with $a_{0}$. Try and determine a pattern to the coefficients from this (note that I didn't actually check to see if your coefficient equation is correct, I'm just assuming it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
$$
(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-4a_n=0 \tag1
$$ you deduce, for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$,
$$
a_{n+2}=\frac4{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n \tag2
$$ giving, with $n:=2p$,
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2(p+1)}&=\frac4{(2p+2)(2p+1)}\:a_{2p}
\\\\&=\frac4{(2p+2)(2p+1)}\cdot \frac4{2p(2p-1)}\:a_{2(p-1)}
\\\\&= \cdots
\\\\&=\frac4{(2p+2)(2p+1)}\cdot \frac4{2p(2p-1)}\cdots \frac4{4\times 3}\:\frac4{2\times 1}\:a_0
\\\\&=\frac{4^{p+2}}{(2(p+1))!}
\end{align}
$$ that is

> $$
> a_{2p}=\frac{4^{p+1}}{(2p)!}
> $$

as announced.

Similarly, with $n=2p+1$, one gets

> $$a_{2p+1}=0$$

due to $a_1=f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Either I am missing something or else something's weird here, since $\;f(x)=\cos2x+3\;$ is a solution to the Differential equation with initial values given, yet in the power series given by the asker I see no alternating signs...

Comment: From your example, we have $f''(x)=-4f(x)$ wich is different from the OP équation: $f''(x)=4f(x)$.

Comment: @Ol Thank you, you're right. I thought I saw a + instead a - .

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $n!$ to get
$$
(n+2)!a_{n+2}=4(n!a_n)
$$
Divide by $2^{n+2}$ to get
$$
2^{-(n+2)}(n+2)!a_{n+2}=2^{-n}n!a_n
$$
which has to be a constant expression for the odd and even indices.